# How to pass jiffle script expression as env parameter through url in GeoServer in SLD style

Tags: geoserver, sld, jiffle

I'd like to create a style for GeoServer for raster algebra using [jiffle](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/jai-ext/wiki/Jiffle).
The main thing is that I want jiffle script to be dynamic (I want to pass the formula through the request URL) and also if possible to provide default value for that expression. I need this because I want to handle different cameras and to provide accurate expression based on camera type. B-G-R-RE-NIR, R-G-B-RE-NIR and so on...

I'm passing jiffle expression through env parameter script2 and I created SLD like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.0.0">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>ndvi</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>ndvi</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Transformation>
          <ogc:Function name="ras:Jiffle">
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>coverage</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>script</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>
                 <ogc:Function name="env">
                    <ogc:Literal>script2</ogc:Literal>
                   <ogc:Literal> red = src[2];green = src[1];nir = src[4];dest = (nir-red)/(nir+red);</ogc:Literal>
                 </ogc:Function>
              </ogc:Literal>   
            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Transformation>
        <Rule>
          <RasterSymbolizer>
            <ChannelSelection>
              <GrayChannel>
                <SourceChannelName>1</SourceChannelName> 
              </GrayChannel>
            </ChannelSelection>
            <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
            <ColorMap>
              <ColorMapEntry color="${env('color_1','#ff0000')}" quantity="-1000" />
              <ColorMapEntry color="${env('color_1','#ff0000')}" quantity="${env('value_1',-1)}" />
              <ColorMapEntry color="${env('color_2','#ffff00')}" quantity="${env('value_2',0)}" />
              <ColorMapEntry color="${env('color_3','#00ff00')}" quantity="${env('value_3',2)}" />
              <ColorMapEntry color="${env('color_3','#00ff00')}" quantity="1000" />
            </ColorMap>
          </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Whole URL looks like this:

```
http://192.168.4.24:8080/geoserver/ws_fe_2459/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&tiled=true&LAYERS=ws_fe_2459:l_871_20191218105647&STYLES=ndvi&ENV=value_1: -0.15842;value_2: -0.032920000000000005;value_3: 0.09258;script2: red = src[2];green = src[1];nir = src[4];dest = (nir-red)/(nir+red);color_1:#ff0000;color_2:#ffff00;color_3:#00ff00&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-122.9095458984375,47.352447509765625,-122.90885925292969,47.35313415527344'
```

and this is the exception that I'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://192.168.4.24:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
      Error rendering coverage on the fast path
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to customize the reader parameters, error is: Parameter script is missing but has min multiplicity &gt; 0
Failed to customize the reader parameters, error is: Parameter script is missing but has min multiplicity &gt; 0
Parameter script is missing but has min multiplicity &gt; 0
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I tried finding documentation about passing jiffle expression through env parameter, but couldn't find anything.

Based on nmtoken comment about using sld_body, I tried passing it through URL.
I redefined style and added *isDefault* tag and style I'm passing through URL looks like this:

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.0.0">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>ws_fe_2459:755_20180606225300</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <isDefault>1</isDefault>
      <Title>ndvi</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Transformation>
          <ogc:Function name="ras:Jiffle">
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>coverage</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>script2</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>
                red = src[0];
                green = src[1];
                nir = src[2];
                dest = (nir-red)/(nir+red);
              </ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Transformation>
        <Rule>
          <RasterSymbolizer>
            <ChannelSelection>
              <GrayChannel>
                <SourceChannelName>1</SourceChannelName> 
              </GrayChannel>
            </ChannelSelection>
            <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
            <ColorMap>
              <ColorMapEntry color="${env('color_1','#ff0000')}" quantity="-1000" />
              <ColorMapEntry color="${env('color_1','#ff0000')}" quantity="${env('value_1',-1)}" />
              <ColorMapEntry color="${env('color_2','#ffff00')}" quantity="${env('value_2',0)}" />
              <ColorMapEntry color="${env('color_3','#00ff00')}" quantity="${env('value_3',2)}" />
              <ColorMapEntry color="${env('color_3','#00ff00')}" quantity="1000" />
            </ColorMap>
          </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

And after quoting this XML string using python urllib *quote* function,
I'm passing sld_body argument in HTTP request like this:

```
http://192.168.4.24:8080/geoserver/ws_fe_2459/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=ws_fe_2459%3Al_871_20191218105647&bbox=-122.914622%2C47.352104006249995%2C-122.907304853744%2C47.356184&width=768&height=428&srs=EPSG%3A4326&format=application/openlayers&sld_body=<quoted_xml>
```

But I'm getting the default map without applied external style that i provided in URL.

Comment: Can you not just send the whole style using SLD_BODY or SLD, rather than using an environment variable

Comment: Could be an escaping issue, the env is using semicolon to separate variables, and you have the semicolon in the script too. Try escaping the ones in the script with backslash, \.

Comment: Why not just have 2 or 3 sld files?

Comment: Andrea, I tried escaping but it didn't work. I simplified formula to a constant value with script2:dest=1\; but I'm still getting errors: now stack trace looks like this: ERROR: missing &apos;;&apos; at &apos;&lt;EOF&gt;&apos;

Comment: Ian, I have about 10 different indexes and 5 camera types so that means I would have to maintain 50 SLD files for now, and possibly more in the future, that's why i would like to make it dynamic if possible.

Comment: In the end, the sld_body approach worked, as @nmtoken suggested. The previous issue with passing style through SLD_BODY was that I quoted whole SLD_BODY argument and that was a mistake. After sending plain unquoted XML as an SLD_BODY argument, it worked.